# how to increase the excel width while download in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

hi all i am using `angularjs` excel download functionality it's working fine but i need to  increase the excel column width while  downloading excel. help anyone how to solve this problem here i attached fiddle

excel download fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/x30v0bym/3/`

Comment: While downloading?

Comment: yes downloading is working fine i need to increase the excel column width while downloading @lin

Comment: @lin  any idea to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML styles to edit the width/anything, and on export these styles will be applied to the final Excel file.

So by adding to your current fiddle..

```
        <th style="width:200px;">Name</th>
        <th style="width:500px;">Email</th>
```

You'll actually accomplish what you're trying to.

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8emjab42/

The exported file will carry over any styles you apply to it in the HTML.

Edit: Wait, I see you say "while downloading" -- does this mean you *don't* want the styles applied until the export? Slightly unclear.

Comment: downloaded excel i need to increase the email column width through code how to do this@invtbl

Comment: i think your fiddle also not working @invtbl check once :)

Comment: Hm, seems to work fine for me.. Setting the <th> width to something insane like 2000px does affect the final Excel file. Do you need a way to do this within the Javascript, instead of in the HTML?